# Is MariaDB cluster execute one query in more than one node?

Tags: cluster-computing, mariadb

if I have  MariaDB cluster, when I run one query, is the cluster execute the query on single node? or it divide the query to all node to be executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it does not.  The galera replication makes sure that data is transparently written to every node but queries are not natively parallelized across nodes.  There are options like the [CONNECT storage engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/storage-engines/connect/), the [Spider storage engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/storage-engines/spider/) and [shard query](https://github.com/greenlion/swanhart-tools/tree/master/shard-query) that can help you parallelize queries.